# Created an android app, worked fine on emulator in debug but did not work properly when installed on actual device

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

So I have an app that worked fine and was (at least I thought) ready for release. I went through the process for preparing for release as described on the developer.android.com site. I emailed the app to myself to install it on my phone, once it was installed it opened but it skipped the first activity (which is a register screen and absolutely neccessary to use the app). I then tried to run the app again on the emulator to make sure that it was still working and the emulator came up saying that the System UI had stopped working. I looked into that error on S.O and google and found something about changing hw.mainkeys = yes instead of = no... this didn't change the results I was getting on the emulator. Does anyone know what I could have done wrong? Maybe something in the app release preparation process? I'm new to programming and would appreciate any help.

Logcat:

```
10-05 15:02:46.775        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ connected to 'boot-properties' qemud service.
10-05 15:02:46.090      925-925/? W/auditd﹕ type=2000 audit(0.0:1): initialized
10-05 15:02:46.170      925-925/? I/auditd﹕ type=1403 audit(0.0:2): policy loaded auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
10-05 15:02:46.170      925-925/? W/auditd﹕ type=1404 audit(0.0:3): enforcing=1 old_enforcing=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
10-05 15:02:46.775        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ receiving..
10-05 15:02:46.775        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ received: dalvik.vm.heapsize=64m
10-05 15:02:46.776        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ receiving..
10-05 15:02:46.776        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ received: ro.config.low_ram=true
10-05 15:02:46.776        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ receiving..
10-05 15:02:46.777        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ received: qemu.sf.lcd_density=480
10-05 15:02:46.777        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ receiving..
10-05 15:02:46.777        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ received: qemu.hw.mainkeys=0
10-05 15:02:46.778        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ receiving..
10-05 15:02:46.778        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ received: qemu.sf.fake_camera=none
10-05 15:02:46.789        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ receiving..
10-05 15:02:46.789        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ received: ro.opengles.version=131072
10-05 15:02:46.789        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ receiving..
10-05 15:02:46.790        0-931/? I/qemu-props﹕ exiting (6 properties set).
10-05 15:02:46.873        0-942/? I/installd﹕ installd firing up
10-05 15:02:47.071        0-937/? I/Netd﹕ Netd 1.0 starting
10-05 15:02:47.073        0-937/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
10-05 15:02:47.073        0-937/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
10-05 15:02:47.073        0-937/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
10-05 15:02:47.073        0-937/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
10-05 15:02:47.073        0-937/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
10-05 15:02:47.073        0-937/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
10-05 15:02:47.073        0-937/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
10-05 15:02:47.073        0-937/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
10-05 15:02:47.536        0-938/? I/﹕ debuggerd: Feb 14 2015 14:21:42
10-05 15:02:47.539      927-927/? I/lowmemorykiller﹕ No kernel memory.pressure_level support (errno=2)
10-05 15:02:47.539      927-927/? E/lowmemorykiller﹕ Kernel does not support memory pressure events or in-kernel low memory killer
--------- beginning of system
10-05 15:02:47.540      929-929/? I/Vold﹕ Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
10-05 15:02:47.540      929-929/? D/Vold﹕ Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
10-05 15:02:47.597      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger is starting
10-05 15:02:47.608      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
10-05 15:02:47.649      929-977/? W/DirectVolume﹕ Deprecated implied prefix pattern detected, please use '/devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0*' instead
10-05 15:02:47.649      929-977/? D/Vold﹕ Volume sdcard state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
10-05 15:02:47.849      930-930/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
10-05 15:02:47.863      930-930/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
10-05 15:02:47.911      930-930/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
10-05 15:02:47.916      930-930/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb6839190, tid 930
10-05 15:02:48.014      930-930/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ hwcomposer module not found
10-05 15:02:48.014      930-930/? W/SurfaceFlinger﹕ no suitable EGLConfig found, trying a simpler query
10-05 15:02:48.015      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ EGL information:
10-05 15:02:48.015      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ vendor    : Android
10-05 15:02:48.015      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
10-05 15:02:48.015      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ extensions: EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_ANDROID_presentation_time EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer
10-05 15:02:48.015      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ Client API: OpenGL_ES
10-05 15:02:48.015      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ EGLSurface: 8-8-8-8, config=0x1
10-05 15:02:48.035      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ OpenGL ES informations:
10-05 15:02:48.035      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ vendor    : Google (Intel)
10-05 15:02:48.035      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ renderer  : Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Intel(R) HD Graphics)
10-05 15:02:48.035      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ version   : OpenGL ES 2.0 (3.1.0 - Build 9.17.10.3347)
10-05 15:02:48.035      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
10-05 15:02:48.036      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 8192
10-05 15:02:48.036      930-930/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 8192
10-05 15:02:48.047      930-930/? D/SurfaceFlinger﹕ Set power mode=2, type=0 flinger=0xb685c000
10-05 15:02:48.400      930-930/? D/SurfaceFlinger﹕ shader cache generated - 24 shaders in 321.270325 ms
10-05 15:02:48.410      941-941/? I/mediaserver﹕ ServiceManager: 0xb5c356a0
10-05 15:02:48.410      941-941/? I/AudioFlinger﹕ Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
10-05 15:02:48.415      941-941/? I/ServiceManager﹕ Waiting for service batterystats...
10-05 15:02:48.734      930-997/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
10-05 15:02:48.736    1049-1070/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
10-05 15:02:48.737    1049-1070/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
10-05 15:02:48.742    1049-1070/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
```

Comment: post the logcat output or stacktrace

Comment: @Ads was able to get the app to run properly when I tried a different device on the emulator (nexus 10 tablet). But still don't understand the original problem which is that the apk would run when installed on a real device.